# Customize field authorization in Spring

Tags: spring-security

In Spring Security, I have a text field that is surrounded by an authorize tag. I want to customize this authorization which can be authorized just in Edit mode. In fact, the user that has this role can only see this field in Insert mode.

If the object is transient, this field should be active, and if the object is persistent, this field should be inactive or invisible.

This is my code:

```
<security:authorize  url="/naturalPersonIdentifier.jsf">
<v:suggestTextEntry id="identifier"
                        maxResultNumber="5"
                        required="true"
                        text="#{naturalPersonBean.naturalPerson.identifier}"
</v:suggestTextEntry>
</security:authorize>
```

Comment: If there is something wrong with my question or It's impossible to do, please tell me to find another solution.thanks

Comment: Most of UI frameworks have ability to enable or disable a component at runtime. Do you really need Spring-Security?